# Call back a function in the original class

Tags: iphone, delegates, methods, callback

I found some useful information on the web but I still can't manage to do it by myself ;)

Ok, let me put my problem in context for you :

I have a first class (myViewController) whose declaration is below :

```
// i just give you relevant information
RssParser *rssParser;
UIActivityIndicator *activityIndicator;
```

In my viewDidLoad method (myViewController) I have :

```
//once again, I summarize it for you
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[rssParser parse];
```

Now, suppose you are in the parserDidEndDocument method (which is in RssParser class), how am I suppose to stop the animation of the activityIndicator ? How can I get access to my instance of activity Indicator from the RssParser class ?

Hope I made myself clear ;)

Thanks guys!

Gauthier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use a delegate. Check the `RssParser` class for the use of a delegate or implement one yourself. Set the delegate of `rssParser` to self in `MyViewController`. Now you can implement the method that is called after the document is parse with `MyViewController`. If you create an ivar for `activityIndicator` then you can easily access `activityIndicator` again.

Comment: Sorry, i should have made myself
clearer ... In fact RssParser is a subclass of NSXMLParser and the reason why i suclassed it is because i want my code to be
clear ! So the delegate is actually RssParser and i want it to communicate with my original class (myViewController). Cheers mate ;)

Comment: Why not let myViewController be the delegate instead of RssParser? You can always implement a second delegate of course.

Comment: Because if myViewController is the delegate, it means I need to implement all delegate methods in myViewController. And it will be a big mess ;)

Comment: Just add an idea, I don't know if this is the best solution but if I put something like that in my delegate (RssParser) :

appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

I think I could get access to myViewController from this point ... what's your thoughts ?

Comment: Might work in this particular case but is not really reusable. Why not  create an alternateDelegate property in RssData and then just set the delegate in myViewController by rssParser.alternateDelegate = self

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understand your last post, could you start it again ?